# Should I be worry after opening suspicious Email attachment?

Tags: email, security, virus, javascript, vulnerabilities

Yesterday, I have received this following suspicious email

[image]

Normally, I would not click on any of the email attachments if I am not sure about the origin of it. But yesterday, I accidentally opened it.

Just to make things clear, I don't recognize the name of the person sending it and I am not expecting any receipt of payment of any kind at the moment. Also, to make things more suspicious, the sender was using a gmail account. If it were for business purpose, all of my contants would use legit company email (eg. john@company.com).

When I opened the attachment file, all I can see is a blank page on both firefox and chrome.

Since the file is in .htm format and not an executable nor zip file, should I be worried that my computer/email is compromised?

**UPDATE 1:**
This is the content of the attachment file:

I am on windows 8.1 64bits, no anti-virus is installed.
[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
What actions should I take so that I can use my laptop safely again? Such as doing on line banking transaction?
Note: I do not have any IT personal to access at the moment. So the most, I will have to re-install the window/ reset the window(windows 8.1 feature) ?

Comment: Yes;  If you opened the file within a browser;  You should indeed be worried.  I would get the help of your IT staff to help you verify what it did exactly.

Comment: You can scan the file attachment at <www.virustotal.com> which will run it through 50+ virus scanners. While I would not consider the results conclusive, if you are told the file is malicious you'll at least have *proof*. That said, the file *is* malicious: 1) You don't know the sender, 2) you never made a payment for which you're expecting a receipt, 3) receipts aren't usually provided as HTML documents, 4) the .HTM file *isn't* an .HTM file of any interest to a human email recipient.

Comment: @Twisty With my limited understanding, the java script from the browser do not have access to any of the file on the harddisk and all it can steal is cookies?Currently, I am wondering how much could that script cause harm to my system?

Comment: @ChrisAung Have a look at [this article](http://askleo.com/can_i_really_catch_an_email_virus_just_by_looking/) in which it states `You can get infected by just looking at the contents of an attachment.`

Comment: It's also worth noting that our concern should not be limited to what malicious code can do if it follows the rules, but rather what it might do if it *breaks the rules* (e.g. by leveraging an exploit).

Answer (score 1):

Without access to the malicious attachment, there really is no way to tell; but yes, I would be slightly worried.  There is rarely a legitimate reason to send a forged email with an attachment.

Another question entirely is whether your system was vulnerable to whatever exploit they were trying to pull off -- the world is still full of Windows XP boxes, and many of the prevalent campaigns still try to focus on this extremely low-hanging, rotting fruit.

If you are one of them, I would certainly advice you to unplug immediately and start to plan mitigation.  A good first step would be to not plug your computer back in to the network until you have a better picture of what happened.  Copy interesting stuff to a USB stick and proceed with caution from a different computer (use an internet café or whatever -- don't surf from your zombie box).

Answer (score 1):

You should get and install good anti-virus software before you do anything else. Run a full scan and you will find out the scale of the problem.

You should never run without anti-virus and firewall protection, unless you never connect to the internet or run software without being 100% certain that it is virus-free.

Comment: FWIW, Windows 8 does include Windows Defender out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You have reason to be worried.
If you want to know what the script does, you can open up the htm file using a text editor, then decode the string using [this tool](http://coderstoolbox.net/string/#!encoding=xml&action=encode&charset=us_ascii). Set string conversion options to URL and Decode. Then you can pretty it up with [js beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/).

There recently was a Firefox 0-day exploit, so this might pretty well be targeting that.